# Wrapping functional JSX components with other functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a functional component that wraps other components and uses JSX in its render method.  I've seen a lot of content online about how to do this with class components, but I'm curious if it works with functional components.

```
function WrappedContent() {
  return <p>I'm wrapped</p>
}

function Wrapper(WrappedComponent) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Wrapped: </p>
      <WrappedComponent />
    </div>
  )
};


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        <WrappedContent />
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with how child components are passed into `<Wrapper>` (via props.children?).

Here's a codesandbox with the above code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/gifted-cray-bqswi

Comment: For next time, note that Stack Overflow's Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). Using on-site snippets helps people help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> (via props.children?)

Yes:

```js
function WrappedContent() {
  return <p>I'm wrapped</p>
}

function Wrapper(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Wrapped: </p>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        <WrappedContent />
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Note that `Wrapper` accepts a parameter called `props`, and uses `props.children`. You could do it with destructuring if you don't have any other props (or even if you do, but it's a small number):

```
function Wrapper({children}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Wrapped: </p>
      {children}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks.

And if I wanted to add an attribute to the `WrappedComponent` like `onDoubleClick` or `ref`?

Comment: @labarna - In `Wrapper`? You wouldn't, the element has already been created before `Wrapper` is called. You'd need to do that in the component passing it to `Wrapper`.

Comment: Got it, ok I'll have to rethink my tact... I'm trying to create an editable Wrapper that display an input (when doubleclicked) and then calls the child component to update its state after editing.

Answer (score 2):

What gets passed to functional components is the `props`, and child elements are contained in `props.children`:

```
function WrappedContent() {
  return <p>I'm wrapped</p>
}

function Wrapper(props) { // <-- here
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Wrapped: </p>
      {props.children} // <-- here
    </div>
  )
};


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        <WrappedContent />
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  )
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/priceless-borg-brlbk

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
function WrappedContent() {
  return <p>I'm wrapped</p>
}

function Wrapper(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Wrapped: </p>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  )
};


function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
        <WrappedContent />
      </Wrapper>
    </div>
  )
}
```

You might also want to refer at this article https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html